# Residue theorem of rational function with real roots in the denominator

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I am studying residue calculations and until now had learned that one should avoid using it for integral of rational functions P/Q when Q has real roots. However, I found an exercise concerning this integral :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}dx $$
which obviously has a real roots for $x=-1$... The answer I saw was to include one half the residue for pole $Z=-1$ when going complex. I never heard of that : could anyone point to any source and explain why it is so ?
Thanks and have a good day !

Marc

Comment: The integral $diverges$. However, you can evaluate its $Principal\ Value$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{r \equiv }$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} - x + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\overbrace{2\pi\ic\lim_{\large x\ \to\ \expo{\ic\pi/3}}\,\,\,
{x - \expo{\ic\pi/3} \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} - x + 1}}}
^{\ds{{2 \over 3}\,\pi\,\ic\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}}}
\\[2mm] - &\
\underbrace{\lim_{\large \epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\,\int_{\pi}^{0}
{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\,\dd\theta \over
\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}
\bracks{\pars{-1}^{2} - \pars{-1} + 1}}}_{\ds{-\,{\pi \ic \over 3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi} \approx 1.8138 \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks  a lot for this relationship ! This result is precisely what you find when taking half the residue associated with $z=-1$ (you get then $1/(3\times2)$ and the residue associated with $z=(1+i\sqrt{3})/2$ which is $-(i\sqrt{3}+1)/6$, and then you get: $2\pi i(1/6 - (i\sqrt{3}+1)/6) = \pi\sqrt{3}/3$, which is precisely the principal value... So is there a problem with calculating it in this way ? Or is it just lucky coincidence ?

Comment: Apparently, this good only for real poles of first order...